# Applying default style for ListViewItem, while using custom behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, attachedbehaviors

I'm using custom behavior for scrolling list view item into current visible view of ListView:

[mvvm how to make a list view auto scroll to a new Item in a list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317194/mvvm-how-to-make-a-list-view-auto-scroll-to-a-new-item-in-a-list-view)

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}"
        BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
        <Setter Property="localBehaviors:ListBoxItemBehavior.IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected" Value="true"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<!-- using Caliburn.Micro's conventions to bind ItemsSource -->
<ListView x:Name="Items" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemContainerStyle}"
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Column #1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ValueOfColumnOne}" />
            <!-- the rest of columns are defined here using DisplayMemberBinding or GridViewColumn.CellTemplate -->
        </GridView
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The problem is that as described in this question on SO, list view items lose their display definition (template I guess):

[ListView losing GridView display when applying ItemContainerStyle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922112/listview-losing-gridview-display-when-applying-itemcontainerstyle)

However, I don't want to redefine template of ListViewItem; i.e. I want to use default, provided by WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just use the ScrollIntoView?  Then focus it.

```
listview.ScrollIntoView(listviewitem);
listviewitem.Focus();
```

Comment: Yes, I ended up creating behavior for ListView, instead. But nevertheless, thanks for the answer.